# Combining querysets obtained from a loop

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Let's say I have a list of people that can be "followed".

I'd like to iterate through all the people that a certain user is following and grab posts from all of those users in the form of a queryset.

I understand that I can combine querysets by using chain or |, but I'm a bit confused when it comes to combining querysets that I might grab from looping through everyone being followed.

```
    following = UserFollows.objects.filter(user_id = user.id)
    for follow in following.iterator():
        UserPost.objects.filter(user=follow.user) #what do I do with this?
```

How would I combine those if I cant explicitly name them to chain or '|'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
following = UserFollows.objects.filter(user__id = user.id).select_related('user')
users_ids = [follow.user.id for follow in following]
posts = UserPost.objects.filter(user__id__in=users_ids)
```

but look that it is quite expensive operation so it's good to add `select_related()` method to fetch users in one query. I think you should also consider to cache the `users_ids` list before get it from database.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like

```
following = UserFollows.objects.filter(user_id = user.id)
q = UserPost.objects.filter(user=following[0].user) 
for follow in following[1:]:
     q = q | UserPost.objects.filter(user=follow.user)
```

Comment: Any idea on how expensive this is compared to the answer below?

Comment: Querysets are lazy if possible. I do not have a small enough Django model at hand right now, but I would guess it translates to a SQL `UNION` query, if db layer is implemented properly. Can you try it out?

Comment: I could certainly try, though I've never done it before. How can I test to see which is faster? Just a simple timer perhaps?

Comment: I think that both solutions are probably equal in terms of speed if you use `select_related()` method. There will be two queries into database: 1st to grab following users and 2nd to grab posts. You can omit one query to database if you cache following users as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Performance tuning of database queries is always tricky and depend on a lot of details such as engine (of course) and also the schema and data you have. Real measurements are always good. Are you experiencing performance problems?